# FIWARE IoT Agent Framework: How to define a device with nested attributes in IoT Agent e.g geo:json?

Tags: fiware

I can't find how to define a device where its entity contains nested attributes.
The need is to pass gps coordinates from a device to an entity having geo:json (like `urn:ngsi-ld:Shelf:unit001` in tutorial https://github.com/FIWARE/tutorials.Entity-Relationships)
Following the https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iot-over-mqtt/index.html the below

```
curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:4041/iot/devices' \
...
  -d '{
 "devices": [
   {
     "device_id":   "motion001",
     "entity_name": "urn:ngsi-ld:Motion:001",
       { "object_id": "c", "name": "count", "type": "Integer" }
     ],
     "static_attributes": [
...
```

creates the count attribute

```
    {
        "id": "Motion:001",
        "type": "Motion",
        "TimeInstant": {
            "type": "DateTime",
            "value": "2020-04-04T07:52:29.00Z",
            "metadata": {}
        },
...
        "count": {
            "type": "Integer",
            "value": "12",
            "metadata": {
                "TimeInstant": {
                    "type": "DateTime",
                    "value": "2020-04-04T07:52:29.00Z"
                }
            }
        },
```

How to replace the count above in order to get the below outcome ?

```
            "type": "geo:json",
            "value": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [13.3986,52.5547]
            },
```

In all examples and documentation the attributes are defined in one level (not nested)  https://iotagent-node-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/index.html.

Tses

Answer (score 1):

Device measures are usually just numbers so for structured elements you either use the expression library or pass data as structured JSON using the IoT Agent for JSON.

That being said, improved GeoJSON support has recently been added to the IoT Agent library, so the following will work on `*:latest` IoT Agent docker images. According to the [Documentation](https://iotagent-node-lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-topics/index.html#geojson-support) various input formats are now possible.

> The defined `type` of any GeoJSON attribute can be any set to any of
> the standard NGSI-v2 GeoJSON types - (e.g. `geo:json`, `geo:point`).
> NGSI-LD formats such as `GeoProperty`, `Point` and `LineString` are
> also accepted `type` values. If the latitude and longitude are
> received as separate measures, the expression
> language can be used to concatenate them.
>
> ```json
>     "entity_type": "GPS",
>     "resource":    "/iot/d",
>     "protocol":    "PDI-IoTA-JSON", ..etc
>     "attributes": [
>         {
>             "name": "location",
>             "type": "geo:json",
>             "expression": "${@lng}, ${@lat}"
>         }
>     ] }
> ```
>
> For `attributes` and `static_attributes` which need to be formatted as
> GeoJSON values, three separate input formats are accepted. Provided
> the `type` is provisioned correctly, the `value` may be defined using
> any of the following formats:
>
> - a comma delimited string
>
> ```json
>   {   "name": "location",   "value": "23, 12.5" }
> ```
>
> - an array of numbers
>
> ```json
>     "name": "location",
>     "value": [23, 12.5] 
>   }
> ```

> - an fully formatted GeoJSON object
>
> ```json
>    {
>     "name": "location",
>     "value": {
>         "type": "Point",
>         "coordinates": [23, 12.5]
>         } 
>    }
> ```

So if your device can send a comma separated long/lat string you should be fine.